# How to log execution order of unit tests in Visual Studio 2019 Test Explorer

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, mstest

We have a legacy code base with some unit tests still coupled by global state (static variables etc.). To find them, I need to know the exact execution order the tests ran when I ran them via VS test explorer.

Is there a way to log execution order in VS test explorer?

I know that vstest.console does output/log the execution order but then I need to narrow down the subset of tests which is very inconvenient with vstest. In VS test runner, i can just run subsets.
I also know that there are other tools (like resharper test runner) but this is also not an option.

Answer (score 0):

Not out of the box that I am aware of, but I guess you can find ways to log it, like have a global counter that you increment in a before method.

But, since the order of the tests are non deterministic by design I am not sure how valuable that information is.

If you know what test are coupled then run those as *Ordered Tests* or use a different test *traits* to control how you execute those test. The best option is of course to break their external dependencies.